# fluent-ffmpeg h264 to gif throwing "error 1"

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, h.264, fluent-ffmpeg

below is my code to convert h264 to gif

```js
var ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
var inFilename = "/home/pi/Videos/video.mp4";
var outFilename = "/home/pi/Videos/video.gif";
var fs = require('fs');
ffmpeg(inFilename)
  .outputOptions("-c:v", "copy")
  .output(outFilename)
  .run();
```

this code works PERFECTLY when it goes from h264 to mp4 just wondering why it doesnt work with h264 to gif or if I could make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem is that in this case you cannot use H.264 inside a GIF file so you have to remove the `outputOptions` line (which tries to *copy* the H.264 video directly to GIF) in order for FFmpeg to reencode the input video.

However, converting video size and frame rate AS-IS to GIF animation is not always a wise thing to do, so I would recommend adding a new option (see for example [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality) for more examples and options) to account for that.

Lets modify the code a bit as a start; lets replace the output options for this case:

```js
var ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
var inFilename = "/home/pi/Videos/video.mp4";
var outFilename = "/home/pi/Videos/video.gif";

ffmpeg(inFilename)
  .outputOption("-vf", "scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,fps=15")
  .save(outFilename);
```

The options here are the same as running FFmpeg directly with:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.h264 -vf scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,fps=15 outputfile.gif
```

The parameters are:

- `scale=320:-1` will scale to width 320 pixels. -1 will use a height proportional to width. You can flip them around to use height as absolute size.
- `flags=lanczos` is the algorithm used to resample the image. lanczos provides good resample quality
- `fps=15` means the GIF will run at about 15 frames per second (FPS).

Comment: yep, this does the trick i changed my code to have your output options and the gif saved correctly

Comment: would you happen to know how to speed up the gif? is there a filter setting I can use for that

Comment: You can play around with the FPS value. If you want to retime you can look at the options used by ffmpeg [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video) and add those to the call chain.

Comment: Was there any particular reason you unaccepted the answer which was for the main question?

Comment: whoops sorry I didn't realize I did that, just re accepted it

Comment: No problem, you're in your full right to unaccept if you decide to do so; I just wondered if the answer didn't solve the original problem so I could update it if needed. However, glad it worked out. Cheers.